# GitHub - How to copy from one branch to another

Tags: bash, github

I git cloned one GitHub repo and checked out one branch.

Then made changes to several files.

How to create another branch and push all changes to a new branch (create new branch and push changes to it using terminal commands)?

Comment: Just create a new branch from the existing branch. Please read a basic Git tutorial, it'll save you many time.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you haven't committed anything yet, you can just use `checkout -b` to create a new branch, then commit your changes:

```
$ git clone ...
$ git checkout original-branch
(Make changes)
$ git checkout -b new-branch
$ git commit -a -m "Message for changes"
```

You talked about "pushing changes" to a new branch - the above would *commit* the changes in the new branch to the local repo. If you wanted to then push that branch back to GitHub, you'd want something like:

```
# Here origin is the name of the remote to push to, and new-branch is the branch
$ git push origin new-branch
```

You'd probably want to make sure you were pushing to your fork rather than to the original repo. You can configure each branch to default to a particular remote and branch, and there are various ways of configuring the default push behavior for new branches too via the `push.default` configuration option. See the [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) docs for more details.